# Create a new SharePoint Site using WCF instead of Sites.asmx - CreateWeb

Tags: wcf, provisioning

I am trying to ascertain whether there is a WCF equivalent of the CreateWeb method in the sites.asmx Web Service to be able to create a new SharePoint site.

I was under the impression that the ASP.NET (asmx) web services are being phased out and Microsoft are encouraging the use of the REST services instead.

I am already using listdata.svc instead of the old list.asmx to query ShareDocuments and Project Documents etc however I cannot seem to find a WCF alternative for CreateWeb.